# Получить поле из JSON посредством Angular 2

Tags: json, angular2, typescript

CRUD-клиент на Angular 2 получает JSON-структуру вида

```
{"productList":[{"id":"1", "name":"название1", "descr":"описание1", ...}, {"id":"2", "name":"название2", "descr":"описание2", ...}, ... ],"size":10}
```

Мне нужно получить отдельно массив продуктов, т.е. значение параметра `productList`. Как это сделать корректно?

Вот часть кода, где я получаю `JSON`-структуру

```
 public getProducts(): Promise<Product[]> {
    let products= this.http.get(this.url)
      .toPromise()
      .then(this.extractProducts)
      .catch(this.handleError);

    return products;
  }

  private extractProducts( response: Response ) {
    let res = response.json();
    let products: Product[] = [];

    for ( let i = 0; i < res.length; i++ ) {
      products.push(new Product({id: res[ i ].id, name: res[ i ].name, descr: res[ i ].descr}));
    }

    return products;
  }
```

Comment: у вас в json только один массив productList

Comment: jsop возвращает promise поэтому перевод лучше сделать до

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуй так:

```
let products = response.json()['productList'] as Product[];
```

по индексу тоже можно

```
let products = response.json()[0] as Product[];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public getProducts(): Promise<Product[]> {
    return this.http.get(this.url)
        .map(res => this.extractProducts(res.productList))
        .toPromise();
}

private extractProducts(res: any[]) {
    let products: Product[] = [];
    for ( let i = 0; i < res.length; i++ ) {
        products.push(new Product({id: res[ i ].id, name: res[ i ].name, descr: res[ i ].descr}));
    }
    return products;
}
```

Comment: вот такая конструкция: res.productList выдает ошибку